# System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve project 'HelloMvc6' from /ap p/src/HelloMvc6

Tags: docker

After I built my image myapp successfully through command:

```
docker build -t myapp .
```

And I step into the last run the container useing:

```
docker run -t -d -p 80:5004 myapp
```

Then I get the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve project 'HelloMvc6' from /ap p/src/HelloMvc6
```

What is the root cause?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your `Dockerfile` and the build context this is hard to answer. But what I see is that there may be a blankspace typo in your `Dockerfile`. Shouldn't

```
/ap p/src/HelloMvc6
```

be

```
/app/src/HelloMvc6
```

instead? Please check your `Dockerfile`.

Comment: Hi h3nrik, nice to meet you again. my work path on my pc is:C:\Users\leiha\Desktop\testdocker\aspnet-Home\samples\latest\HelloMvc and my Dockerfile is:FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-beta4
ADD . /app
WORKDIR /app
RUN ["dnu", "restore"]

EXPOSE 5004
ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "./src/HelloMvc6", "kestrel"]

Comment: BTW, it has another path which is :C:\Users\leiha\Desktop\testdocker\aspnet-Home\samples\1.0.0-beta4\HelloMvc. so is I work at wrong path?